# Showing two versions of the central limit theorem are equivalent (are they?)

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to read [Norris' book on Markov chains](https://cape.fcfm.buap.mx/jdzf/cursos/procesos/libros/norris.pdf). In particular, at page 160 he states the central limit theorem :

**Theorem 4.4.1 (Central limit theorem). Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables with mean 0 and variance $t ∈ (0,∞)$. Then, for all bounded continuous functions $f$, as $n → ∞$ we have
$\mathbb{E}[f(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/\sqrt{n}]\to \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\phi_t(x)dx$**

I thought until now that the central limit theorem was

**Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables with mean 0 and variance $t ∈ (0,∞)$. Then, for all bounded continuous functions $f$, as $n → ∞$ we have
$(X_1+\ldots X_n)/\sqrt{n}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,t)$, where "$\xrightarrow{d}$" denotes convergence in distribution.**

I don't really understand if these are equivalent. In the first theorem, $f$ has to be bounded so we cannot take the identity $f(x)=x$ which is not bounded right?

And I don't understand how to see that these formulation are equivalent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y_n \to Y$ in distribution if and only if $Ef(Y_n) \to Ef(Y)$ for every bounded continuous function $f$. [ For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables ]

If $Y$ has a density $\phi$ then we can write $Ef(Y)$ as $\int f(x)\phi (x) dx$. In our case the density is $\phi_t$ defined by $\phi_t(x)=\frac 1 {t\sqrt {2 \pi}}e^{-x^{2}/2t}$.

Comment: Thank you @Kavi. But why would one express the CLT in this way? It seems more complicated no?

Comment: Convergence of distributions is often handled using several other equivalent conditions . See Portmantau's Theorem in the link I gave. Many times we don't prove convergence in distribution  by directly verifying that the distributions converge (at continuity points of the limit). The first version of the theorem is quite useful in some situations.  @roi_saumon

Comment: Okay. One last thing : in theorem 4.4.3 he defines a process $X^{(c)}_t$, rescaled from a random walk $X_t $and then proves for all continuous bounded function $f$ and $0\le t_1 <\ldots <t_m$, we have $\mathbb{E}[f(X_{t_1}^{(c)},\ldots,X_{t_m}^{(c)}]\to \mathbb{E}[f(\sigma B_{t_1},\ldots,\sigma B_{t_m}]$ as $c\to 0$. So using the same characterisation of convergence in distribution that you mentionned and $m=1$ we have in particular $X_t^{(c)}\xrightarrow{d} \sigma B_t$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: thanks! It is more clear now